# How do I build my project stripped down?

Tags: backbone.js, npm, browserify, marionette

I am using Browserify to build my project, but the output file is ~1.5m.  There's not that much source in it, so how do I strip out the non-production stuff?

```
BUILDDIR = public
MODULESDIR = ./node_modules/.bin
build:
    @mkdir -p public & \
    $(MODULESDIR)/browserify app/initialize.js \
    -t node-underscorify \
    -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] \
    -t [jstify --noMinify] \
    -o $(BUILDDIR)/out.js -d

server:
    $(MODULESDIR)/http-server &\

start: build server

clean:
    @rm -rf public

.PHONY: clean
```

The project is Marionette and Backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by either removing the -d parameter, creating a dev task or event using the exorcist, as suggested in the [browserify handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#source-maps).

On my setup i use [budo](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo) as dev server and have separated make tasks for dev and release.